# C++ factorial function with data type issues

Tags: c++

I made a function that calculates factorial numbers from 0 to 16 ( none negative and reasonably small)

but it wont go past n15
any idea what data type i should be using and where?

```
long factorial(long num1)
{
    long f;

    if (num1 >= 0 && num1 <= 16)  
    {
        for (long i = 0; i <=num1; i++)
        {
            if (i==0) f = 1;
            else f=f * i;
        }
        return f;
    }
    return 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Why `double`? Is this supposed to be the Gamma function?

Comment: fixed I was testing doubles at first then went to longs as I got higher

Comment: `16!` should fit in a `long`, so the data type is fine. What exactly is happening when you input `15` to the function?

Comment: its returning 2004310016 its looking like there is a double in my main

Comment: @Someguy Note that `double` is not an integral type, it's an extended-precision *floating-point* type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using a 32bits system, otherwise it would work.

The maximum number you can represent on a 32bits integer is 2^31 (you have to save a bit for the sign).

Depending on your architecture (your question cannot be answered without this information), a `long` may be stored on 32bits, and thus you cannot represent accurately 16! because it is bigger than 2^31.

Look for a specific extension of your compiler / architecture to guarantee you have 64 bits storage (it is not guaranteed by the standard, which does not dictate how much bits the types must have, it just sets inequalities between types storage size).

Comment: Looks like the real proble is that im forced to use doubles in main.

Comment: The problem I see is that 15! is over one trillion, so how does it work?

Comment: With C++11 you can use a `long long int` which is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_long_long_int)

Comment: 1 trillion fits in a 64 bits integer.

Comment: its 1307674368000 to be exact it appears that the doubles I'm using in my main is inhibiting me from going any higher than 11

Comment: @Mic, okay, counterpoint: 16! definitely fits in a 64-bit number, so why would it not work when 15! does?

Answer (score 1):

Change `long` to `long long`:

```
long long factorial(long num1)
{
    long long f;
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the library [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/) - should enable one to store and use very large numbers